# SQL Execute a procedure only when the table is not empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I have a SQL query that tells me all the orders that we have open and when should we ship them by.
I wanted to create a routine email blast that alerts people to all the orders that need to be shipped today.

This is my code

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'AMT',
    @recipients = 'test@test.com',
    @body = 'results -- some body goes here',
    @subject = 'Sensible subject goes here ',
    @query = 'SELECT Order, ShipByDate, HoursLeft FROM OrdersTable WHERE HoursLeft < 24'
```

This code works. The only problem is that, when there are no orders with less than 24 hours or when the result is empty, it sends an empty table email with the same subject and body.

I want to have like an if statement before EXEC line that checks if the OrdersTable is empty under the 24 hours or less condition. Is this possible? I know for exec you use IF instead of CASE but I'm not sure how to check if the table is empty.

Comment: You say *"Like an `IF` statement"*, so are you saying you don't want an `IF` statement? If so, why not?

Comment: It is better to execute procedure each time and check the conditions beside the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't an `IF` statement do what you want?

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OrdersTable WHERE HoursLeft < 24))
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'AMT',
        @recipients = 'test@test.com',
        @body = 'results -- some body goes here',
        @subject = 'Sensible subject goes here ',
        @query = 'SELECT Order, ShipByDate, HoursLeft FROM OrdersTable WHERE HoursLeft < 24';
END;
```